# Is it possible that |$\mathbb R$| is an inaccessible cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I know that |$\mathbb R$| can be any cardinal with cofinaly not equal to $\aleph_0$. Does this include inaccessible cardinals?
And what would be the consequences if |$\mathbb R$| = $\kappa$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "inaccessible" - [**strongly** inaccessible or **weakly** inaccessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal).

Since a strongly inaccessible $\kappa$ is by definition uncountable *and bigger than $2^\lambda$ for every $\lambda<\kappa$*, we can't have $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ be strongly inaccessible.

On the other hand, we **can** have $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ be weakly inaccessible (that is, a regular limit cardinal), at least assuming that the existence of weakly inaccessible cardinals is consistent with ZFC. The proof that this is possible uses [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)), but if you've already seen forcing then here's the outline:

- Suppose $V$ is a model of ZFC with an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$.
- Consider $L^V$, that is, $V$'s version of [the constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).
- In $L^V$, the Continuum Hypothesis holds and $\kappa$ is still weakly inaccessible - so in $L^V$ we have $2^{\aleph_0}<\kappa$.
- Now we force: add $\kappa$-many Cohen reals. Since this forcing is c.c.c., it preserves cardinals and cofinalities, so $\kappa$ remains a weakly inaccessible cardinal; but now $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$. *(Actually, all that's obvious is that $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\kappa$; it takes an argument, using "nice names," to show that in fact we have equality. This isn't hard but it's worth pointing out.)*

Meanwhile, as far as consequences of $2^{\aleph_0}$ being weakly inaccessible go, I'm not aware of any big ones beyond the obvious (e.g. CH isn't true).

---

Some further comments:

- In the proof sketch above, why did I need to pass to $L$ instead of working in $V$? Well, we could have in $V$ that $2^{\aleph_0}>\kappa$, in which case adding $\kappa$-many Cohen reals *won't* make $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$. Instead, if we want to handle this case without going to $L$ we need to *collapse a cardinal*: force with the set of partial maps from $\kappa$ to $\mathbb{R}$ whose domains have cardinality $<\kappa$. Since this is $(<\kappa)$-closed, $\kappa$ will stay weakly inaccessible.
- What if I try to run the same argument as above, but with $\kappa$ strongly inaccessible? Well, now in the last bullet point, I need to argue somehow that $\kappa$ remains strongly inaccessible after forcing, and this breaks down: specifically, there is no reason to have $2^\lambda<\kappa$ for all $\lambda<\kappa$ after we force.
- Finally, it's worth pointing out that there **are** senses in which $\kappa=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ can "appear" strongly inaccessible (or more): namely, by looking at $\kappa$ in an [**inner model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model) $M$ (e.g. $M=L$). This inner model could be much smaller than $V$, and in particular it could be wrong about how the powerset function works: we'll always have $(2^\lambda)^M\le (2^\lambda)^V$, but not necessarily conversely. So it's totally possible to have e.g. "$2^{\aleph_0}$ is strongly inaccessible in $L$" (in fact, this will be true whenever $2^{\aleph_0}$ is weakly inaccessible, since weakly inaccessible cardinals are strongly inaccessible in $L$ since $L$ satisfies the GCH!). If you're interested in understanding how properties can differ between an inner model and the whole model, the term to look for is ["absoluteness."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness)