# How many cardinals exist between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$?

Tags: set-theory

Assuming the negation of the continuum hypothesis, there is a set $G_1 \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that if $\aleph^\prime_1$ is the cardinality of $G_1$, then $\aleph_0 < \aleph^\prime_1 < \mathfrak c$.

> Do there exist models of set theory in which there exist another set, say $G_2$ such that $\aleph_0 < \aleph^\prime_1 < \aleph^\prime _2 < \mathfrak c$ with $\aleph^\prime _2$ the cardinality of $G_2$ and so on (that is, the cardinality of $G_2$ is bigger than that of $G_1$ and less than the cardinal of the set if real numbers)?
>
> Is it possible to repeat this process and find sets with larger and larger cardinalities which still are less than $\mathfrak c$? If the answer is yes, what are the consequences of this assumption in analysis?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem

Comment: It seems that Easton theorem you mentioned is about power sets (as it is well known, power set of $\mathbb N$ has cardinality of continuum). My question is about subsets of $\mathbb R$ which their cardinals are neither one of $\mathbb N$ nor $\mathbb R$. I want to know whether continuum hypothesis fails, how many cardinals exist between them @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: @HamedPourmohammad The cardinality of the continuum is exactly determined by the number of smaller cardinals.

Comment: What this means is that *the failure of CH tells us basically nothing about what $2^{\aleph_0}$ is* - it just tells us that $2^{\aleph_0}\not=\aleph_1$. Essentially, besides the obvious restriction - [that $2^{\aleph_0}$ has uncountable cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)#K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_and_cofinality) - ZFC can't prove anything about the size of the continuum.

Comment: As a starting point, you might be happy with the following theorem: Suppose $M$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC, and $\kappa$ is an $M$-cardinal (that is, $\kappa\in M$ and $M\models$"$\kappa$ is a cardinal"). Then there is a forcing extension $N$ of $M$ such that the cardinals of $N$ are exactly the cardinals of $M$ and $N\models$ "$2^{\aleph_0}\ge\kappa$." Proof: add $\kappa$-many Cohen reals to $M$, and use the [countable chain condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)#The_countable_chain_condition).

Comment: As an example of Easton's theorem, it's consistent with ZFC to assume, for example, $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{2018}$.  (Though meta-theoretically, it seems unlikely that any "reasonable" new axiom which would settle the question would have this in particular as its result.)

Comment: The number of cardinal numbers between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$ can be any cardinal number from $0$ to $\mathfrak c$ inclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a quick comment: you've phrased your question in terms of $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ and sets of reals. However, it's much easier to talk instead in terms of powersets and cardinals $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, and this gives the same result (since $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\vert\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\vert$ and every cardinal $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of some set of reals and vice versa). That is, your question is just

> How big can $2^{\aleph_0}$ be?

and this is how I treat it below.

---

It turns out that basically nothing can be said about $2^{\aleph_0}$ in ZFC alone. Specifically, while [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)#K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_and_cofinality) tells us that $\mathfrak{c}$ must have uncountable cofinality, that's basically all that can be said. This was proved by Solovay, and later [extended dramatically by Easton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem).

A very small case of Solovay's result is the following:

> For any $n>0$, it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_n$.

For example, we can have $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{17}$. Even more is possible however: we could have $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$, or $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, or even be [weakly inaccessible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415670/is-it-possible-that-mathbb-r-is-an-inaccessible-cardinal).

The whole situation can best be summed up as follows:

> Suppose $M$ is a countable (= so that we can actually force over it) model of ZFC, and $\kappa$ is an $M$-cardinal (= $\kappa\in M$ and $M\models$"$\kappa$ is a cardinal"). Then there is a forcing extension $N$ of $M$ such that $(i)$ the cardinals of $M$ are exactly the cardinals of $N$, and $(ii)$ $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\kappa$.

The proof is a straightforward forcing argument: let $G$ be generic over $M$ for the forcing $\mathbb{P}$ which adds $\kappa$-many Cohen reals (specifically, elements of $\mathbb{P}$ are finite partial maps from $\kappa\times\omega$ to $2$, and we order $\mathbb{P}$ by reverse extension). Let $N=M[G]$. We clearly have in $N$ an injection $\kappa\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$, and the fact that $Card^M=Card^N$ follows from the fact that [$\mathbb{P}$ has the countable chain condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)#The_countable_chain_condition).

So in a precise sense, **there is absolutely no ZFC-provable bound on the size of $2^{\aleph_0}$**.

---

Finally, you ask about the possible impacts on analysis of a large continuum. To the best of my knowledge there are very few of these (and fewer still that aren't simply [equivalents of $\neg$CH right off the bat](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2140&context=gradreports)). However, there are interesting set-theoretic propositions which imply a large continuum and which have meaningful analytic consequences: e.g. [cardinal characteristic inequalities](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&ved=0ahUKEwjWiqPCt7_YAhXCTd8KHY5XCn0QFgiDATAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.lsa.umich.edu%2F~ablass%2Fhbk.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0IR-P7A9EdK9p63YfC96V5) or [forcing axioms](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/Raach_notes.pdf). But in general, simply knowing that the continuum is large doesn't really tell you very much.

Comment: The continuum being a real measurable cardinal has arguably a big impact on analysis.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Sure, but I didn't say there weren't any - just that there seem to be few.

Comment: Point taken.$~$